# How to read comma separated values into a Struct object?

Tags: c++

I am currently working on a program that will read comma-separated values into various objects which I can call upon in my main function.

Here is the struct:

```
Struct Company {
    string abbreviation;
    string company_name;
    int purchase_level;
    double price;
    double inflation_rate;
    double deflation_rate;
}
```

And here are a few lines of the data:

```
// file.txt
// Company Name, Abbreviation, Purchase Level, Price, Inflation Rate, Deflation Rate
Company 1, CONE, 1, 100, 1.03, 0.87
Company 2, CTWO, 1, 150, 1.17, 0.78
...
company_name, abbreviation, purchase_level, price, inflation_rate, deflation_rate
```

Is there a possible way for me to create separate objects from a .txt file or a .csv file using **ifstream**? This is just for a general project I'm working on; what is the simplest or most effective way to read the file and extract the values into separate objects. For example, I'd like to create an object with the following values:

```
// Object 1 (Company_1)
Company_1.company_name = "Company 1";
Company_1.abbreviation = "CONE";
Company_1.purchase_level = 1;
Company_1.inflation_rate = 1.03;
Company_1.deflation_rate = 0.87;
```

Thanks, and have a great day!

Comment: You probably want `std::vector<Company> companies;` and add an operator >> for your struct: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-input-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=msvc-170](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-input-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Please, please, please, search StackOverflow for "C++ read struct CSV", or search the internet:  "C++ read struct Comma Separated Values".

Comment: To answer your question:  Yes, [there are methods to read CSV file into struct](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%2B%2B+read+file+struct+CSV&rlz=1C1GCEB_enUS935US935&oq=C%2B%2B+read+file+struct+CSV&aqs=chrome..69i57.10582j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Hint:  `std::getline(my_istream, my_string, ',')`;

Comment: I'd use Boost [Spirit X3](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/index.html), and make a grammar to parse the input and produce a vector of Company objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to read in data from a CSV file, I'd suggest using a library. The problem is that some data items, like string, may use comma as an ordinary character, in which case the data are usually embraced within the quotation marks, and the quotation marks inside such strings are doubled. So you need a parser. Another problem is that in some countries people use the comma as the decimal point, so you can find them just inside numbers.

That said, this is how I process a **tab**-separated CSV file

```
    std::ifstream in("my_file.csv");
    // check if the file was really opened
    // ...
    std::string header, line;
    // read the header, if any, perhaps check its integrity
    std::getline(in, header);  
    if (auto n = header.find("blah blah"); n == std::string::npos)
    {
        throw std::logic_error("'blah blah' not found - missing header?");
    }
    while (std::getline(in, line))
    {
        std::istringstream S(line);
        std::string token;
        // I know there are 9 columns in the table
        std::array<std::string, 9> tokens;
        for (auto& token : tokens)
        {
            // replace '\t' with ',' for comma-separated data
            std::getline(S, token, '\t'); 
            clean(token); // remove spurious white spaces and other "input bugs"
        }
        // read an int
        auto id = std::stoi(tokens[0]);
        // read a string
        auto title = tokens[1];
        // read a float.
        // to_float is my function that converts commas into dots 
        // and then converts the string into a float
        // should be using std::locale, but not perfectly sure, 
        //  'cos I have files with both dots and commas as decimal points
        auto score = to_float(tokens[2]);
        // etc. for the remaining data fields 
        // Then do something with the data, 
        // e.g., form a data record and push / emplace it back to a vector 
    }
```

With this you'll certainly be able to read a CSV (comma-separated values) file.

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to the other answers, I would like to add a different approach: reading the file during compilation (I realize that this may or may not be usable in your situation, but in some situations this is the simplest solution).

First, transform the `.txt` file into valid source code as follows (e.g. using [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) or `awk` if that is available to you):

```
// file.txt
// Company Name, Abbreviation, Purchase Level, Price, Inflation Rate, Deflation Rate
{"Company 1", "CONE", 1, 100, 1.03, 0.87},
{"Company 2", "CTWO", 1, 150, 1.17, 0.78},
```

Then do the following:

```
struct Company {
    string abbreviation;
    string company_name;
    int purchase_level;
    double price;
    double inflation_rate;
    double deflation_rate;
};

Company companies[] = {
#include "file.txt"
};
```

Now `companies` will be an array of structures with the data from `file.txt`.